# Eclipse can't find source file for debugging

Tags: c++, eclipse, gdb, eclipse-cdt

Trying to debug simple c++ project that was checkout like new project from Eclipse IDE and was created like "Makefile Project with existing code" by wizard later.

I placed breakpoints and started debugger. Got error:

```
No source available for "main() at 0x400c6c"
```

How to make `Eclipse` to see source?

UPD

Adding source code:

a.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
 printf( "hello world" );

}
```

makefile

```
all:a

a.o:a.cpp
    gcc -c a.cpp
```

Looks like problem in "non Eclipse style" `makefile`. What is the best way to fix such imported non eclipse project?

Comment: could i see the code?  it might help

Comment: Did you build with `-g`?

Comment: I have updated question body with code. And I don't build with -g.  I was expecting that Eclipse will manage everything :) . I would like to click Icons Run/Debug without editing makefile. What is the best way to organize this project in this case?